# Incomplete class in session in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, class, session, constructor

The problem I have is that when I am getting a class stored in session the result is an incomplete class.

```
class Users {

    function __construct(){
        FunctionsHelper::includeFiles(
            array(
                ADMINISTRATOR_MODEL_DIRECTORY . 'model.php',
                ADMINISTRATOR_MODEL_DIRECTORY . 'user.php'
            )
        );
    }

    public function setLoggedUser($user){       
        if (session_id() == "")
            session_start();
        $_SESSION['ATT_user'] = $user;
    }

    public function getLoggedUser(){
        if (session_id() == "")
            session_start();

        if (!isset($_SESSION['ATT_user'])) {
            return new User();
        }

        $loggedUser = $_SESSION['ATT_user'];
        $UserId = $logedUser->getUserId();
        if (empty($UserId)) {
            return new User();
        }

        return $loggedUser;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call the method `getLoggedUser()`. `$_SESSION['ATT_user']` stores an `User` object that must be recovered.
The problem is that in the `__construct` function I am including the file that loads the `User` class so I do not understand why the error I get. The `FunctionsHelper::includeFiles` function include the files but also if I calls the include function as the first line in the `getLoggedUser` function the `$_SESSION` array will still have the incomplete object.
Different is if I do a `print_r` inside `setLoggedUser()`. The `$_SESSION` contains the completed object!!
Can anyone explain me help me please?!

I am using IIS 7 instead of Apache.

Comment: Use class autoloading with help of `composer`. http://getcomposer.org You won't have to manually include files and avoid such problems.

Comment: Is not there another option that does not require to include another file?

Comment: You could implement your own autoloading system, see: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php